# Is it safe to just delete unwanted apps from my OEM?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, filesystems, oem, system-recovery

Also I am having difficulty searching by the app codes to work out which is which.

Can anyone point me to some resources for cleaning up my OEM, or how to install a fresh copy of Windows 10 onto one of my 2 OEM partitions? (Currently the installer can’t find either recovery drive. But my whole file system seems mucked up.)

(Windows Refresh is not offering me the option to start over with everything fresh, with new profiles and files. Not sure if this is WAI or related to what’s wrong with my system. I have used it and it took off depreciated apps which was nice, but I also wanted a totally fresh start without reloading my corrupted OEM.)

Comment: Ps, there’s no Windows-10-refresh tag and I have insufficient reputation to create it.

Comment: Yes, it's safe to remove OEM apps except some app related to power management, driver related management. First, I would like to say, we need to use OEM image to make sure the activation can work fine after reinstallation. If you would like to clean the unwanted apps, under Apps&Features, uninstall the app without Microsoft manufacturer could be only way to clean up the Windows on your PC.

Comment: I have done system refresh and other uninstallation work, so there are no apps other than Windows apps and manufacturer drivers that can be uninstalled via usual means. But of course Apps & Features cannot change anything in the OEM.

Comment: By chance do you actually want to use Fresh Start?  The tag you want created isn’t really necessary.

Comment: I have already used Fresh Start, however I probably typed the name incorrectly. Thanks for the correct name. It didn’t offer the option to start totally afresh, as I mentioned in my OP. Unsure if this is missing an option on my particular device, or what.

Comment: PC Decrapifier will do what you want safely....https://www.pcdecrapifier.com/

Comment: Will it? I have previously watched a YouTube explanation of this and it looks like the same result as other uninstall tools I have used: it appears to remove things *after* they have been installed onto your system. I am looking to remove things *before* doing factory reset so they *never get installed in the first place* (when resetting;fortunately or  unfortunately I am not looking for a time machine).

Comment: @KatteeLee, I am not sure how to “use the OEM image to make sure the activation can work after reinstallation”? I thought the Windows activation key was stored on the EFI partition? Can you explain what you have in mind a bit further?

Comment: OEM activation is valid as long as the customer uses the OEM-provided image on a system. To create a customized image, customers can use the image provided by the OEM as the basis for creating the custom image. Otherwise, a different activation method must be used.  For further details on customizing Windows and activation impacts refer to the following whitepaper. OEM activation is applicable to computers with Windows installed that are purchased through OEM channels.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I found a link with that title referenced at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2a622582-3ba8-47d6-8b55-cc6d8881cb0e/windows-7-oem-activation, but when following it, there’s a 404 error. I am not really sure what an OEM channel purchase is. I bought mine through a store directed at end users. I don’t build computers or anything. I just want to modify what apps load from my OEM. Or figure out how to direct my machine to use the other OEM, which I think was made by Windows 10 updates probably.

Comment: Or figure out how to use one of the existing OEM drives to save a fresh copy of Windows 10 and use that for reset. Or figure out if Fresh Start is supposed to be offering me an option to start over with a new profile instead of saving my profiles and files, and enable this option if it should be there.